# Go getting failed field from UnmarshalTypeError

Tags: go

According to GO stdlib, there is an error returned when JSON property type is different than struct's one. Here is definition:

```
// An UnmarshalTypeError describes a JSON value that was
// not appropriate for a value of a specific Go type.
type UnmarshalTypeError struct {
    Value  string       // description of JSON value - "bool", "array", "number -5"
    Type   reflect.Type // type of Go value it could not be assigned to
    Offset int64        // error occurred after reading Offset bytes
    Struct string       // name of the struct type containing the field
    Field  string       // name of the field holding the Go value
}
```

Now, I'm trying to simulate a type conversion fail, by having an string field inside struct and providing int to this one.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Sample struct {
    StringProp string `json:"a_string"`
}

func main(){
    jsonString := `{ "a_string" : 1 }`
    s := Sample{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &s)
    if err != nil {
        typeErr := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError)
        fmt.Print(typeErr.Field)
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the error doesn't have any values for "Struct" or "Field" property. What are these properties for?
Is there a way to detect at which property unmarshal failed?

Comment: But they do have values, the error struct is like this: `{Value:number Type:string Offset:16 Struct:Sample Field:a_string}`, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rNCjaLM4y6r). What is your question?

Comment: @icza interesting. Playground gives me a different result comparing to my local one. Will check what's wrong with my environment...

Comment: It also works on my local computer, so if you get something else, it must be your environment. What is the output of `go version` and `go env`?

Comment: go version go1.11.1 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was reproduced only on my local environment. After removing golang(I had 3 version installed with brew) and installing go once again, it started to work as expected. `Struct` and `Field` are populating again.

Also, there is an [issue on github GO repository](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27275)